# How can I use dot sourcing to run code from a variable in the same instance?

Tags: powershell, variables

I have a variable that stores a command that I would like to execute.

ex:

```
$C = "echo 'test'"
```

I have one way to execute this by using the following:

```
powershell .($C)
```

however this opens a new instance of powershell. How can I go about executing that code in the same instance? I can't seem to find a way to use dot sourcing without opening that second instance.

EDIT: I can not use IEX

Comment: `& ([scriptblock]::Create($C))` and `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.InvokeScript($C)` almost the same as `IEX`.

Comment: as usual I love you Santiago ha

Comment: Linked duplicates have in depth details as well as ways you can restrict potential arbitrary code